# How to resolve java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: “123412341234”?

Tags: java, sql, swing, awt, numberformatexception

I am not able to enter 12 digit account number into database. I am using Java Swing and Oracle JDBC.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
    For input string: "123412341234"
```

Comment: Well presumably you're trying to parse that as an `int`. That value is too big for an `int`. Note that this error has nothing to do with SQL, Swing or AWT.

Comment: `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is `2147483647` so trying to parse anything bigger than that to an `int` will give you an exception.

Answer (score 0):

BigInteger accountNumber =  new BigInteger("12345678900123");

Answer (score -1):

Please check database field data type. if it is integer convert it to integer and send it to database..

Comment: Please explain in detail

Comment: That error has thrown because you have given string value to integer datatype value..so what you can do is convert the string to integer and send it to database. Integer.parseInt is the method to convert the string to integer..